# Trying to prove concurrence of altitudes of a triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles, vectors

I know that this question had been asked before, but I am not exactly following what the answers say. Doing my own way here: I am puuzzled how to continue?
[image]

I named the points A,B,C, and the foot of the perpendiculars D and E. Now the point D would be like: $$d=kb+(1-k)c$$
Also it must satisfy $$(d-a)\cdot(c-b)=0$$
Now I use another set of vectors:
$$\alpha=a-b,\beta=b-c,\gamma=c-a$$
So I end up with:
$$d=b+\frac{\alpha.\beta}{\beta.\beta}\beta$$
Now for the orthocentre$(h)$ would be like:
$$h=ma+(1-m)d=nc+(1-n)e\\m(a-d)-n(c-e)=e-d$$
Now how can I get $m,n$? and prove concurrence?

Comment: The technique you are using depends on expressing everything in terms of scalar multiples of two linearly independent vectors. Then when you get a vector equation at the end, you can equate coefficients and have two equations for the two unknowns $m, n$.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that the two altitudes intersect? That seems quite easy by contradiction (suppose they're parallel) ...

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee no concurrence instead

Comment: Doesn't [concurrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_lines) *mean* intersecting at one point? If you show they're not parallel, you're done ... ?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee concurrency is generally used for three or more lines imo, i haven't drawn the third altitude. I'm considering that too.

Comment: @ADG Oops, sorry ... thought you only wanted to prove the two lines

Comment: @ADG you can prove the concurrence of altitudes using Ceva's theorem and similar triangles. I'm not sure how to proceed with your vectors though. Would that be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Linear equations

When you write $ma+(1−m)d=nc+(1−n)e$ or $m(a−d)−n(c−e)=e−d$ you have a linear system of equations: two equations (one for each coordinate of the resulting vector) in two variables ($m$ and $n$). You could write that in matrix and vector notation, as

$$\begin{pmatrix}a_1-d_1 & e_1-c_1\\a_2-d_2 & e_2-c_2\end{pmatrix}
\cdot\begin{pmatrix}m\\n\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}e_1-d_1\\e_2-d_2\end{pmatrix}$$

Solving that will usually break down to either Gaussian elimination or the computation of an inverse matrix. So I don't see how you could keep your vector notation without jumping through hoops for it.

## Anternative: Descriptive not constructive

If your end goal is prooving that the altitudes intersect, you have another option: you can proove that there exists a point $h$ satisfying

$$(a-h)\cdot(b-c)=0\qquad (b-h)\cdot(c-a)=0\qquad (c-h)\cdot(a-b)=0$$

i.e. such that the line connecting $h$ to one of the corners is orthogonal to the edge opposite that corner. Reformulating the above you get

$$a\cdot(b-c)=h\cdot(b-c)\qquad b\cdot(c-a)=h\cdot(c-a)\qquad c\cdot(a-b)=h\cdot(a-b)$$

This, too, can be written as a system of linear equations:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
b_1-c_1 & b_2-c_2 \\
c_1-a_1 & c_2-a_2 \\
a_1-b_1 & a_2-b_2
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot\begin{pmatrix} h_1 \\ h_2 \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
a\cdot(b-c) \\
b\cdot(c-a) \\
c\cdot(a-b)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

In this setup, you'd have to proove that the system of linear equations still has a solution, although it is over-determined. You can prove this by showing that the third row is a linear combination of the first two rows. It's the same linear combination both on the left and on the right hand side of the equals sign. Therefore, any $h$ which satisfies the first two equations will satisfy the third as well.

## Alternative: Projective Geometry

As an alternative, I'd tackle this using projective geometry and homogeneous coordinates. There, a point $(x,y)$ is represented by a vector $(x,y,1)^T$ or any multiple thereof. The line joining two points can be computed using the cross product, as can be the point of intersection between two lines. The matrix $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,0)$ multiplied with a line will yield a point at infinity orthogonal to that line. So you'd get

$$d=((D\cdot(b\times c))\times a)\times(b\times c)$$

as „join $b$ and $c$, take the point at infinity orthogonal to that, connect it with $a$ and intersect the result with the line joining $b$ and $c$.“ But you don't actually need the point $d$, you only need the altitude. So you'd have to show that the following three lines are concurrent:

$$
(D\cdot(b\times c))\times a\qquad
(D\cdot(c\times a))\times b\qquad
(D\cdot(a\times b))\times c
$$

Three lines are concurrent if the determinant formed by their vectors is zero. So you could plug the above in a determinant, use variables as the coordinates of the vectors, and in the end obtain a big zero confirming your claim.

Of course, understanding *why* all this machinery works as claimed requires quite a bit of work, and exceeds the scope of this answer post. I just had the impression that you'd prefer to give closed form expressions for geometric objects, and projective geometry is great for this.